# Js animate a ball wrong, slow then faster everytime

Tags: javascript, animation

When I run this code first time the animation speed is slow, then every time faster.The code moves a ball, and after you touch the screen, the ball goes to where you touched.

But the first time, it is very slow, then every time it goes faster. Why？

I was expecting a similar speed, not perfectly constant, but not like that.
Also on the tenth attempt the ball goes too fast.

I try on my smartphone, I don't know if it will work on a computer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
.point{
    width:10px; height:10px; 
    background-color:green;
    position:absolute;
}
#ball{
    width:10px; height:10px;
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
    top:1px; left:50px;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="point"></div>
<div id="ball"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.addEventListener("touchstart", function(e){
       var cx = e.touches[0].clientX;
       var cy = e.touches[0].clientY;
    });

    window.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e){
       var cx = e.touches[0].clientX;
       var cy = e.touches[0].clientY;
       endB = [cx, cy];
    });

    window.addEventListener("touchend", function(e){
       decl();
    });

    function decl(){
       isBmove = true;
       mstep = 2;
       requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }

    function step(ts){
       if (isBmove){
           var dfrein = 25;
           var gb = b.getBoundingClientRect();
           var ang = Math.atan2(endB[1]-gb.top, endB[0]-gb.left);
           var addX = Math.cos(ang)*mstep;
           var addY = Math.sin(ang)*mstep;
           var difX = endB[0]-gb.left;
           var difY = endB[1]-gb.top;
           var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(difX,2),Math.pow(difY,2));
           if(dist < dfrein){
               mstep *= 0.98;
                l("m= "+mstep);
           }
           if (mstep < 1){
               isBmove = false; 
               l("add :"+addX+","+addY);
           }
           b.style.top = gb.top+addY+"px";
           b.style.left = gb.left+addX+"px";
      }
      requestAnimationFrame(step);
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame = 
    window.requestAnimationFrame 
    || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame 
    || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame 
    || window.msRequestAnimationFrame; 


    var isBmove = false;
    var endB = [0,0];
    var mstep = 2;
    var b = document.getElementById("ball");
    function l(p){
    console.log(p);
}

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, it is because you require a new animation frame everytime you call your `touchend` event listener, that way calling the `decl()` function. So, maybe try getting the `requestAnimationFrame(step)` out of the `decl()`. Like so:

```
// Instead of:
function decl(){
  isBmove = true;
  mstep = 2;
  requestAnimationFrame(step);
}
// Try like this:
function decl() {
 isBmove = true;
 mstep = 2;
}
requestAnimationFrame(step)
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Petar is correct.  For what it's worth, here's a version of your app changed to work on mouse events.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .point {
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            background-color: green;
            position: absolute;
        }

        #ball {
            width: 10px;
            height: 10px;
            background-color: red;
            position: absolute;
            top: 1px;
            left: 50px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class="point"></div>
    <div id="ball"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) {
            var cx = e.clientX;
            var cy = e.clientY;
        });
        window.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) {
            var cx = e.clientX;
            var cy = e.clientY;
            endB = [cx, cy];
        });
        window.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) {
            decl();
        });
        function decl() {
            isBmove = true;
            mstep = 2;
        }
        function step(ts) {
            if (isBmove) {
                var dfrein = 25;
                var gb = b.getBoundingClientRect();
                var ang = Math.atan2(endB[1] - gb.top, endB[0] - gb.left);
                var addX = Math.cos(ang) * mstep;
                var addY = Math.sin(ang) * mstep;
                var difX = endB[0] - gb.left;
                var difY = endB[1] - gb.top;
                var dist = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(difX, 2), Math.pow(difY, 2));
                if (dist < dfrein) {
                    mstep *= 0.98;
                    l("m= " + mstep);
                }
                if (mstep < 1) {
                    isBmove = false;
                }
                l("add :" + addX + "," + addY);
                b.style.top = gb.top + addY + "px";
                b.style.left = gb.left + addX + "px";
            }
            requestAnimationFrame(step);
        }

        requestAnimationFrame(step);

        window.requestAnimationFrame =
            window.requestAnimationFrame
            || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame
            || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame
            || window.msRequestAnimationFrame;


        var isBmove = false;
        var endB = [0, 0];
        var mstep = 2;
        var b = document.getElementById("ball");
        function l(p) {
            console.log(p);
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```